# Magento creating custom attribute with custom validations

Tags: magento

I need to create an attribute. Also i need to validate that attribute value. So i created a new .js file and add some functions. Then in setup file, i call the function name. But after creating the attribute that validation class wont come with the field.

```
$installer->addAttribute(MageTest_Module_Model_Name::ENTITY, 'test_value', array(
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Test Value',
    'backend'       => '',
    'user_defined'  => false,
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'position'    => 60,
    'class'         => 'validate-testValue',
    'note'          => 'This should contains 2 digits. Example 00',
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));
```

'validate-testValue' is my js function name. Can anyone help me to solve this please.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

to use Magento form validator you have to register your method with the **Validator** object.

Try something like that in your custom js file

```
Validation.add('validate-testValue','HERE your error message if the field is not valid',function(fieldValue) {
return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(fieldValue) || fieldValue == "testValue";
});
```

Ok, this example will only validate if your field value is "testValue", not very usefull.
But you can adapt it I guess :)

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. I just did this , but it is not working within my custom.js file. I put the code into validation.js and checked. Then it is working. Why is that. Can anyone help me. Please.